# Xcode MARK: Shortcut

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I accidentally button mashed my keyboard and Xcode inserted

`// MARK: - <#MyProtocolName#>`

What is the keyboard shortcut to have Xcode insert that MARK: comment?

I haven't customized Xcode and it was able to read my protocol name and put it into the code highlighted area.

```
// MARK: - Actionable
struct Foobar: Actionable
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a shortcut you created and and forgot about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one Command we have to use before any function or Methods or top of Coding line.

COMMAND + OPTION + /

If It is top of collectionView methods it will be like

```
// MARK: - CollectionView Methods
```

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

```
/// Collection Views for Fetured, Popular, Categories
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - collectionView: Data to be provided by service. Collection Views are categoriesCollectionView, popularCollectionView, feturedCollectionView
///   - section: retturn Value from Service
/// - Returns: return Value from Service


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return homeList.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut is: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: @james-webster It's scope contextual